# Raku: Installation of Gnome::Gtk3 on Windows

Tags: gtk3, raku, zef

I am trying to install the Raku module «Gnome::Gtk3» module on a Windows pc, without success.

```
Powershell> zef install Gnome::Gtk3
```

This fails with a lot of "Cannot locate native library"-messages.

I have installed Raku with choco, along with git. And have fixed the path.
That alone took quite some time to figure out, due to missing documentation.

I have installed Gtk, as described here: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows

But Raku is unable to locate the libraries. Is this something that can work, or do
I have to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

(I am aware of the «GTK::Simple» module, but cannot use that as a replacement as it lacks support for keyboard interrupts - which I need.
I have installed it, as it states that it installs the GTK dll's as well.)

Comment: I tried this with MSYS2 and it also fails, see [this](https://github.com/MARTIMM/gnome-gtk3/issues/13) GitHub issue.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make this kind of modules work, you need the `-dev` version of the library, that is, the DLLs which are actually the ones that [NativeCall](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#ABI/API_version) uses. [This tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/gtk3/example/14881/installation-or-setup) shows how to set them up for C++ and Python, Raku shouldn't be too different.

Comment: Would that be the same dll's that GTK::Simple has bundled here: https://gtk-dlls.p6c.org/

Comment: @ArneSommer looks like that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This now installs on MSYS2, Windows 10. First download the latest version of rakudo from [here](https://rakudo.org/downloads) and extract the zip file to e.g. `C:\rakudo-2020.11`. Then [install MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org), and when finished open the MSYS2 terminal window and install the following packages:

```
$ pacman -Syu
$ pacman -S base-devel gcc git libcrypt-devel libreadline
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

Then add the following to the MSYS2 `~/.bashrc` configuration file:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig
export PATH="$PATH:/c/rakudo-2020.11/bin:/c/rakudo-2020.11/share/perl6/site/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/mingw64/bin"
```

Save the updated `.bashrc` and reload it from the MSYS2 terminal prompt:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Finally, install `Gnome::Gtk3`:

```
$ zef install Gnome::Gtk3
```

Comment: it does not work. I have done everuthing as decribed, but "zef install Gnome::Gtk3" fails
"Cannot locate native library 'gobject-2.0-0.dll': error 0x7e".

Comment: Do you have the .dll file installed? If I run `file /mingw64/bin/libgobject-2.0-0.dll` from the MSYS2 terminal window, I get:
`/mingw64/bin/libgobject-2.0-0.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows`

Comment: I get the same result as the above. (And I tried to install the module again, after booting the pc today, but it failed again.)

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/d/rakudo-2020.12/bin:/d/rakudo-2020.12/share/perl6/site/bin:/mingw64/bin

Comment: Can you try [this](https://pastebin.com/dGjDY6Av) simple debug program? It works fine here, do you get an error message?

Comment: Ok then my suggestion would be to download [Gnome::GObject](https://github.com/MARTIMM/gnome-gobject) and run the tests manually to get closer to the problem. I would also would suggest that you file a [new issue](https://github.com/MARTIMM/gnome-gtk3/issues) reporting the problem to the author.

Comment: Finnsen Sommer@DESKTOP-4159HST MSYS ~/tmp/gnome-gobject
$ prove6
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling D:\msys64\home\Finnsen Sommer\tmp\gnome-gobject/t\Boxed.t
Could not find Gnome::N::X in:
    inst#D:\msys64\home\Finnsen Sommer\.raku
    inst#D:\rakudo-2020.12\share\perl6\site
    inst#D:\rakudo-2020.12\share\perl6\vendor
    inst#D:\rakudo-2020.12\share\perl6\core
    ap#
    nqp#
    perl5#
at D:\msys64\home\Finnsen Sommer\tmp\gnome-gobject/t\Boxed.t:5
t\Boxed.t .. Dubious, test returned 1

Comment: It fails to find Gnome::N::X (as shown above), Gnome::GObject::Type and Gnome::GObject::Value.